# combining multiple SSAS queries as one dataset

Tags: ssas

I have a fact-table with one date dimension linked three times to attributes for Ordered, Prepared and Shipped dates.  So, I am able to get counts on ordering, manufacturing and dispatch and currently I am running these as three separate excel pivot table requests and combining them into one graphs giving three bars per month.  I am wondering if there is a more sleek way I should be doing this by which I write a query which returns the three separate counts as individual measures rather than running the query three times doing it once against each dimension.

```
Currently, the fact table looks something like this: -
DEPID, PRODCODE, ORDERDATE, PROCESSDATE,SHIPDATE
001,001,20120101,20120102,20120104
002,001,20120103,20120105,20120106
003,002,20120104,20120106,20120107
004,002,20120105,20120107,20120108
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create 3 calculated measures in the cube (Ordering Count, Manufacturing Count, Dispatch Count)...then just drag them into your pivot table in the values section and use a date dimension in the rows group.